# Use user input as path to save file in Python 3?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, filepath, download

I'm writing a script to download a file from a website, and I'm able to successfully save the file using a path entered into the code, however if I use an input then things don't work.

```
path = input("Save Location: ")
```

From here I'll use `os.path.join` to append the file type to the end of the path and then use PycURL to download the file. But getting a user input for the path gives a FileNotFoundError, for example `C:/Users/MyName/Desktop` become `C:UsersMyNameDesktop/v.mp4` after appending the file type. I've also tried `C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop` as well as `C:\/Users\/MyName\/Desktop` however they give the same thing, and ideally I'd like to avoid using double forward/back slashes in the input since they're not very user friendly.

If for whatever reason you need any more code/all the code don't hesitate to ask. Thanks :)

Comment: show your code with `os.path.join`  and `C:/Users/MyName/Desktop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath

```
>>> x = input()
C:/Users/MyName/Desktop
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(x, 'v.mp4'))
'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\v.mp4'
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something very similar to this but this seems to work. Not sure why mine didn't but hey. This one does :)